# Angular :How to Show the same modal with different content onClick different buttons?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a same open pop modal with 2 different button one for add product 
setting and another for Edit product setting.how should i hide the button for same modal on click of add product setting it should show create button and on click of edit button setting button it show hide  create button and show update button ?

```
<!-- modal footer -->
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button md-raised-button color="primary"   id="CreateProduct" (click)="CreateProductsetting()">Create</button>
   <!--<button md-raised-button color="primary"   id="Editproduct" (click)="EditProductsetting()">Update</button>-->
   <button md-raised-button class="cancel-button"  data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I expected the output for same pop modal with different functionality that is one for add product setting and another for edit product setting.

Comment: I would suggest to keep seperate page for both functionality and use that page/form in a single dialog module!

Comment: You can use a structural directive like [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#ngif) if you want to hide an element based on a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general question seems to be:

> How to show or hide certain parts of a reusable component?

## Option 1: *ngIf

The ngIf directive creates and destroys components based on the evaluation of a condition.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button md-raised-button color="primary" *ngIf="isCreating"   id="CreateProduct" (click)="CreateProductsetting()">Create</button>
   <button md-raised-button color="primary" *ngIf="isEditing"   id="Editproduct" (click)="EditProductsetting()">Update</button>
   <button md-raised-button class="cancel-button"  data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And in `*.component.ts`:

```
class MyComponent {
  public isEditing: boolean = false;
  public isCreating: boolean = true;
}
```

And set the value of `isEditing` and `isCreating` to `true/false` whenever you'd like to show/hide the edit buttons.

## Option 2: style.display attribute binding

You can set the css property `display` to `none` to hide the elements.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button md-raised-button color="primary" [style.display]="isCreating ? 'block' : 'none'"   id="CreateProduct" (click)="CreateProductsetting()">Create</button>
   <button md-raised-button color="primary" [style.display]="isEditing ? 'block' : 'none'"   id="Editproduct" (click)="EditProductsetting()">Update</button>
   <button md-raised-button class="cancel-button"  data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

## Option 3: Use the same button, but change the label and callback

You can switch out the label and action of a single button depending on the state of the component:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button md-raised-button color="primary" id="productAction" (click)="(isCreating ? CreateProductsetting : EditProductSetting)()">{{isCreating ? 'Create' : 'Update'}}</button>
   <button md-raised-button class="cancel-button"  data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem Vishal, if the answer helped you, you can accept the answer. If you think it's a qualitative answer you can also upvote it. You can do this using the grey checkmark and voting buttons.